# Scala - Error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: upickle/core/Types$Writer

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, upickle

I'm new to Scala/Spark, so please be easy on me :)

I'm trying to run an EMR cluster on AWS, running the jar file I packed with `sbt package`.
When I run the code locally, it is working perfectly fine, but when  I'm running it in the AWS EMR cluster, I'm getting an error:

`ERROR Client: Application diagnostics message: User class threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: upickle/core/Types$Writer`

From what I understand, this error originates in the dependencies of the scala/spark versions.

So I'm using Scala 2.12 with spark 3.0.1, and in AWS I'm using emr-6.2.0.

Here's my build.sbt:

```
scalaVersion := "2.12.14"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk" % "1.11.792"
libraryDependencies += "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-core" % "1.11.792"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-aws" % "3.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "3.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "3.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "3.0.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "upickle" % "1.4.1"
libraryDependencies += "com.lihaoyi" %% "ujson" % "1.4.1"
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `sbt package`, the generated jar will contain only the code of your project, but not dependencies.  You need to use `sbt assembly` to generate so-called uberjar, that will include dependencies as well.

But in your cases, it's recommended to mark Spark and Hadoop (and maybe AWS) dependencies as `Provided` - they should be already included into the EMR runtime.  Use something like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "3.0.1" % Provided
```

Comment: God bless you, sir!

Comment: For those who are new to `sbt` like myself, it might be worth noting that you first have to add `sbt-assembly` as a plugin. To do so, create a file called `plugins.sbt` under the `project/` folder of, well, your project. In that file, paste: `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")`. Then you can run `sbt assembly` from the command line.